# Задача о банкомате (алгоритм решения)

Tags: алгоритм

Подскажите пожалуйста идею решения данной задачи. Как обычную задачу о банкомате я решать примерно представляю. А что изменится тут?

> Покупка
> У покупателя имеется набор N монет A1 ≤ A2 ≤ ... ≤ AN, каждой монеты ровно по одной штуке.
> Найти наименьшую стоимость предмета, который нельзя купить, используя только эти монеты.
>
> ```
> Input format
> Output format
> Examples
>
> Input Output
> 5       32
> 1
> 2
> 4
> 8
> 16
> ```

Comment: что то я не догоняю почему output 32, ведь сумма всех монет 36 а это больше 32, значит вполне можно купить этот предмет !?

Comment: @ampawd без сдачи, видимо

Comment: @zRrr так ведь можно и без сдачи, 16 + 8 + 5 + 2 + 1 == 32

Comment: N=5, далее ввод монет: 1,2,4,8,16. Сумма: 1+2+4+8+16=31.

Comment: Какие налагаются ограничения на N и достоинства монет?

Answer (score 2):

Отсортируем достоинство монет по возрастанию. После чего начинаем проверку от минимальных. Когда для очередной монеты её стоимость превышает сумму предыдущих монет более чем на 1, минимальная сумма, которую нельзя уплатить, равна сумме предыдущих монет + 1.

Для упрощения программной реализации (чтобы не обрабатывать отдельно случай, когда такой монеты нет - вот как в исходном примере) можно добавить в набор фэйк-монету стоимостью более чем сумма всех монет плюс один.

Схематично:

```
input "Количество монет=";n
dim coins(0 to n)
sum=0
for i = 0 to n-1
    input coins(i)
    sum=sum+coins(i)
next i
coins(n)=sum+2
coins=sort(coins, asc)
sum=0
for i = 0 to n
    if coins(i) > sum+1 then
        print sum+1
        exit program
    else
        sum=sum+coins(i)
    end if
next i
```

Comment: PS. Решение не зависит от того, есть дубликаты достоинств монет или нет. Просто если есть - надо вводить их по одной, несколько раз одинаковое достоинство.